# How to connect RODE videomic Pro to audio interface

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces, rode

I'm a filmmaker, and I want to buy a Rode Videmic Pro. Both for field recording, and voice-overs.

([https://www.amazon.com/Rode-VideoMicPro-Directional-Microphone-Shockmount/dp/B00YAZHRZM/ref=dp_ob_title_ce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YAZHRZM))

Since I want to record voice-overs, I will need to connect the mic to my audio interface; which is a Behringer u-phoria um2.

As you may know, the rode mic comes with an RCA output; but the interface comes with an XLR input.

**So how do I connect it? Is there some kind of adapter? Will it work?**

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm a filmmaker, and I want to buy a Rode Videmic Pro.". 

No. You don't. You really don't. You might think you do, but take it from someone who has already experienced the pain. You actually don't.

Comment: @Mark, why? Is it a bad mic?

Comment: I think I have already answered that question.

Comment: @Mark No, you haven't.
Allow me to ask why do you think it's a bad microphone, so I can reasonably and rationally decide if such item will properly suit my needs or if it will turn out as a burden in my filmmaking career.

Comment: You asked me if it is a bad mic. It is. The one I used fell apart and had appalling audio quality. In my opinion it is not fit for purpose.

Comment: @Mark Hmmm... thanks for the above-provided information. 
I will investigate deeper into this; to properly make a reasonable desition for both the good of my career and of others whom my advice might seek upon stumbling into this delicate topic.

Comment: John, you will find very few career filmmakers that are using this type of equipment for the application you have stated. Hobbyists, consumers maybe but not anyone who is seriously considering a career in this field.

Comment: @Mark you mean Voice Over?
Well, I know. But I don't really have an option.
Thanks for your kind help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Røde make one - the VXLR+ - it also converts the voltage required for phantom power.

Example from just the first store I found one - https://www.thomann.de/gb/rode_vxlr_416774.htm

[image]

> - Plug adapter with power converter
> - TRS Mini-jack (3.5 mm) to XLR 3M
> - Integrated voltage converter from phantom power (12 - 48 V) to plug-in power (3 - 5 V)
> - Allows operation of Rode HS2, VideoMic GO and VideoMicro on professional XLR microphone inputs with phantom power

Different types at https://www.amazon.com/s?k=rode+vxlr%2B&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

If you don't need phantom, then just a '3.5mm (TRS) Mini-Jack Female Microphone Adapter to 3-pin XLR Male Connector' as this example...

[https://www.amazon.com/Movo-Mini-Jack-Microphone-Connector-Camcorders/dp/B071WN5RDV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WN5RDV)